# xcode SpriteKit New game template

Tags: templates

hi I'm trying to learn SpriteKit
But all the Tutorials I have read The game Template has a GameView.swift file and a GameView.SKs file and it loads a hello world where you click on the screen it adds a sprite of a space ship.

The one with Xcode 6.2 has no gameView.Swift or GameView.SKs file I've tried adding these by going add new file Cocoa Touch Class
subclass of SKScene
add import SpriteKit
new file resources SpriteKit scene

but can't seem to get it to work ?
is there a tutorial I'm missing of how to do this.
hope somebody can point me in the right direction cheers

Comment: Did you definitely select Swift as the language?

Comment: hi thanks yes i did select swift  it works but it has a 3d jet that you can rotate zoom etc .

Comment: You may have selected SceneKit instead of SpriteKit...

Comment: oh thanks What a Twit i am you can't believe how much time I've spent on this . I will go away and hang my head in shame